# Is this correct to Initialize a matrix in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class with an variable of array of array.

```
private  double * array[4][4];
```

Can I initialize it this way?

```
void RealMatrix::init(int i, int j) {
    this->array[i][j] = new double;
    *(this->array[i][j]) = 0;
}
```

Comment: With an array that small I would not make it on the heap. just do  `double array[4][4];` and avoid memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will dynamically allocate a single `double` and set the pointer that is element `[i][j]` of the 2D array to point to that `double`. It then assigns the value 0 to that `double`. You can do this in a single line with:

```
this->array[i][j] = new double(); // value-initialization
```

Or you can more explicitly set it to `0` with:

```
this->array[i][j] = new double(0); // direct-initialization
```

However, unless you have a very good reason, you'll probably be better off just having your array member contain `double`s rather than `double*`s:

```
double array[4][4];
```

There's no point dynamically allocating something unless you have to. I can't imagine you having a good reason for an array so small.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. However, if I were in your shoes, I'd get rid of the `double` pointer (unless there are some specific reasons you're doing things this way).

Comment: Does it initialize the whole matrix or just a single element of array[i][j]?

Comment: @ericyoung: The method only initializes a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `vector<double>`.

```
class Matrix {
    std::vector<double> values;
    const unsigned int width;
public:
    Matrix(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
    : values(width * height), width(width) {
    }

    double& value(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) {
        return values[i + (width * j))];
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
Matrix matrix(10, 20);
matrix.value(3, 4) = 15;
```